# Getting System.Char[] instead of value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert double to binary, but when I run my project, I get `System.Char[]` in my text box instead of binary values. How can I solve this problem?

```
 int bitCount = sizeof(float) * 8; 
            char[] result = new char[bitCount]; 


            int intValue = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(testvalue), 0);

            for (int bit = 0; bit < bitCount; ++bit)
            {
                int maskedValue = intValue & (1 << bit); 
                if (maskedValue > 0)
                    maskedValue = 1;

                result[bitCount - bit - 1] = maskedValue.ToString()[0];
            }

              new string(result); 
              richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text+"\n"+result;
           // pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: `new string(result)` returns a string, you have it just sitting there all on its lonesome. Assign it to a string or use it in the concatenation.

Comment: @adricadar, ToString() on a character array returns the type name, i.e. "System.Char[]", which is why that's what shows up in the text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> new string(result);

This is the problem. You do not assign this to any variable. I believe you should use it instead of `result` when you assing to `textbox.Text`.
You get `System.Char[]` in your text box, because `ToString()` for char arrays returns such a string.
So try following:

```
String resultString = new string(result); 
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + resultString;
```